# Facebook: get list of accounts/pages that a user is admin of, using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Im confuse why its working on  Graph API explorer but when I'm going to use the FB Javascript SDK its not working, it didn't show any accounts listed.

Graph API Explorer(Working it show a list of accounts/pages where user is admin)

```
me/accounts
```

Javascript SDK(Not working it didn't show a list of accounts/pages where user is admin)

```
FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        /* make the API call */
        FB.api(
            "/me/accounts",
            function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    }
}, {scope:'email,manage_pages,publish_pages'});
```

Comment: What is not working? What is response? Did the user grant the permissions?

Comment: @WizKid the response is empty. I'm the one working on it. I use the scope to give the permission.